# how to cancel segue if both UITextFields contain text

Tags: swift, uitextfield, segue, uipickerview

I have two UITextFields one is a normal UITextField the other is a UITextField connected to an UIPickerView. I want only one of them to respond to Mybutton and perform the correct segue To ViewControllerA if the info inserted in the fields is correct and matches my array of strings, and to ViewControllerB if the inserted text does not match my array. The UIPickerView entered text will most certainly be correct.. The only situation would be if there was text inside both of the fields how can i construct an UIAlert so when the button is pressed the action doesn't happen. or to hide my UIButton if both fields contain text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your segue conditional, you need to use `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` as below.

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if identifier == "segue1Identifier"{
            //check for required conditions
            //if conditions setisfy : return true
            //else return false : this will not allow segue to perform, so prepareForSegue:sender: will not call
        }
    }
```

Comment: If i use, shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier, Do i need to implement PerformSegueWithIdentifier also?

Comment: yes you have to, if you want to pass data to nextViewController,

Comment: performSegueWithIdentifier: will be call after shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier: , if shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier: returns true